# What's an easy way to set up a role for developers giving them access to all stuff devs normally do?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to set up a role for all the devs on the team. I figure they ought to have the ability to create, drop, use, etc., all the normal kinds of stuff in the database - tables, sequences, functions, and all that kind of stuff. And they should have it both for existing objects in the DB, as well as for any new stuff that's created.

I figure it ought to start as something like this

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO role_developer;    
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO role_developer;
```

to cover first the existing stuff, and then all the future stuff that hasn't yet been created.

I'm also concerned with what's implied by **ALL** privileges, but can't find a concise list of what's included in "all".

Assuming that's correct, then I need a list of all those types of objects that I should do this for -- TABLES, SEQUENCES, and so on, but I haven't been able to find a simple, understandable list of them.

As a long-time SQL Server developer, I'm having a hard time getting my head around this difference in the way security is modeled in PostgreSQL.

Comment: "*can't find a concise list of what's included in all*" - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html#SQL-GRANT-DESCRIPTION-OBJECTS

Comment: thanks, that helps with "what does ALL mean". Now I just need to find the list of all objects that are relevant to normal developers, that I should apply that to.

Comment: to answer the question you have to define what is athe "all stuff devs normally do?"

Comment: Well, that's kinda the question for me, too. Since I'm coming from SQL Server, I'm not familiar with all of this yet. For example, sequences are a whole new thing that I wouldn't know to look for. As I was first starting to write some basic queries yesterday, I was getting errors about not having privilege for relations. It turns out that this message was completely stupid, it has nothing to do with "relations" as such - there were no FKs in the table at all. So I'm looking to head off the confusion when developers, trying to do something new, are misled into thinking that it doesn't work.

Comment: A *relation* is a table or view or sequence. Give default privileges for tables and sequences and you are probably good. Look at the documentation for `GRANT` to see what types of objects have what permissions and deal out privileges according to need.